# Elastic Beanstalk console can't select Graviton instance type

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-graviton

In the AWS Elastic Beanstalk web console for an existing environment, under "Configuration" -> "Capacity" -> "Instance Types", **I can't select a Graviton instance**, e.g. `c6g.large`, `m6g.large`, or `r6g.large`.  None of those appear on the list of options, but `c6i.large`, `m6i.large`, and `r6i.large` *do* appear.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**An Elastic Beanstalk environment gets created with architecture set to either x86 or arm64, and it can never be changed** after creation.  If your environment is set to x86 architecture, only the `c6i`, `m6i`, `r6i`, etc. series will appear.  To use Graviton instances, you'll need to create a new Elastic Beanstalk environment and set its architecture to arm64.  According to the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.ec2.html):

> By default, Elastic Beanstalk selects the x86 processor architecture
> when you create a new environment. You can choose the processor
> architecture (x86, arm64) for the instance types only when you’re
> creating a new environment. After you create an environment, you can
> only change the instance types to others within the same processor
> architecture of your running environment. You can't change the
> processor architecture.

If you're creating a new environment via the AWS web console, you need to select "Configure more options" -> "Capacity" -> "Processor" to select arm64 architecture.

Comment: This seems to apply only to the EB console; it's possible via aws cli or here e.g. via PowerShell: `Update-EBEnvironment -OptionSetting @( New-Object -TypeName "Amazon.ElasticBeanstalk.Model.ConfigurationOptionSetting" -ArgumentList "aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration", "InstanceType", "t4g.large" )`

Answer (score -1):

It's possible to change the instance type to another architecture via the AWS CLI. For example, an existing `amd_x64` environment with ID `$ENVIRONMENT_ID`, can be changed to use `t4g.medium` arm64/Graviton instances with:

```
aws elasticbeanstalk update-environment --environment-id=$ENVIRONMENT_ID \
  --option-settings=Namespace=aws:ec2:instances,OptionName=InstanceTypes,Value=t4g.medium
```

The architecture ('Processor' in the AWS Console), will be updated to `arm64`.

Comment: This doesn't work, a configuration validation exception will be thrown

Comment: @TauraiBenhura I've checked the above and fixed the typo in `--option-settings`. Definitely works with Tomcat 8.5 / Corretto 8. Not sure why you'd get a configuration validation exception though. Are you on a recent platform version?